# Objective function binary variable is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working on an optimisation problem. I am trying to figure out if the objective function is convex/concave. I have taken derivative by simplifying the summations.

\begin{align}
 \sum_{n = 1}^{N} b_n  \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{k} {\sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j=1}^g  a_{nij} x_{ij}}} 
\end{align}

where $a_{nij} \geq 0$ and $x_{ij}$ is a binary variable.  Suppose $\sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j=1}^g a_{nij} x_{ij} = y_n$ then say,
\begin{align}
f(y_n) &= \frac{1}{1+k/y_n}\\
f'(y_n) &= \frac{k}{(1+k/y_n)^2 y_n^2}\\
f''(y_n) &= \frac{-2ky_n}{(1+k/y_n)^3 y_n^4}
\end{align}

Since  $a_{nij} \geq 0$ and $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ then $y_n \geq 0$. Hence $f''(y_n) \leq 0$, therefore the objective function is concave.

Can you please help to understand if this approach is correct?

Comment: Sure change as per your suggestion

Comment: No the decision variable is $x_{ij}$. so only discrete optimisation variables

Comment: Then it is clearly non-convex. Choose two points in that discrete set and draw a line segment connecting them.  Does the entire line segment belong to that discrete set?

Comment: Sorry, would you mind giving me a reference/example to do the above mentioned for a binary discrete set? Thanks...

Comment: [From](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7b9.png) chapter 1 of Nocedal & Wright's *Numerical Optimization*.